# How to style the top select all checkbox alone in MUI React data grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, datagrid

I am using data grid with multiple selection with Material UI React. For the headings, I have added dark background color and light text color. For the select all checkbox at the top also, I want to add the dark background color and light line color so that it looks uniform. For the headings, I was able to do it with the following code. I was trying to do the same for the checkbox but was not able to. Only the heading row, I want to change like this. The checkboxes in the normal rows needs to be the same. Could someone please help with this?

```
          sx={{
            '.MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitleContainer': {
                backgroundColor: '#014181',
                color: 'white'
            }
          }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, except it did not set the actual checkbox outline to white. You can do so like this:

```
sx={{
  ".MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitleContainer": {
    backgroundColor: "#014181",
    color: "white",
    ".MuiSvgIcon-root": {
      color: "white",
    },
  },
}}
```